# Overflow-x: hidden breaks data-spy scroll

Tags: jquery, iphone, scroll, overflow, smooth-scrolling

I'm having this issue on a project I'm working on. 
The page is responsive, but on iphone i can shift the page a little bit to the right and left. I tried to fix this with overflow-x:hidden on the body.

But somehow this is breaking up the smoothscroll of the menu.

The page can be found here [on this website](http://jointhecontest.nl/photocontest)

Hopefully someone here knows a solution!

Answer (score 2):

solved it by removing body:height:100%